# Let $U$ be orthogonal. How can I prove that $||UA||_2=||A||_2$?

Tags: normed-spaces, orthonormal

Let $U$ be orthogonal. How can I prove that $||UA||_2=||A||_2$?

---

I know that $||UA||_2\le||U||_2||A||_2$ and I also know that as $U$ is orthogonal, $U^{-1}=U^T$. But I don't know what else to do...

Comment: $\|UAx\|_2=\|Ax\|_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: since $U^TU=I$, $(UA)^TUA=A^TU^TUA=\cdots$

Comment: Oh so, I know that $||UA||_2^2=(UA)^T UA=A^T A$ and $||A||_2^2=A^T A$. So can I say that if $||UA||_2^2 = ||A||_2^2$, is true that $||UA||_2 = ||A||_2$ ???

Comment: @User160 You've glossed over one subtlety explained in the last comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899919/56861). To finish, take the square root.