# How do we compute $(a+b)^2$ for vectors or matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-regression

I was going through the vector representation for linear regression. The error has been defined as

$$
Error = {(y_i - x_i^tw)}^2
$$

where $y_i$ is a scalar, $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector and $w$ is also a $n \times 1$ vector.

On the next line, it has been simplified to

$$
Error = {y_i}^2  -2w^tx_iy_i + w^tx_ix_i^tw
$$

Can someone explain how did we reach the second notion through a series of steps?

Comment: If they're all vectors, you can't even define $y_i-x_i^tw$.

Comment: aah, I have corrected the description now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x_i\cdot w$ is a scalar,$$(y_i-x_i\cdot w)^2=y_i^2-2x_i\cdot wy_i+(x_i\cdot w)(x_i\cdot w).$$The rest is [an abuse of notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899919/56861) identifying $x_i\cdot w$ with $x_i^tw$ and $w^tx_i$.