# Are the entries of diag($xx^T$) given by $x^Tx$?

Tags: vectors, quadratic-forms, transpose

If $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector, are the entries of diag($xx^T$) given by $x^Tx$?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by diag$(xx^T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^Tx$ is a [$1\times1$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899919). It can't contain the $n$ diagonal values you seek. Instead, their *sum* is $(x^Tx)_{11}$. Using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation),$$(x^Tx)_{11}=x_ix^i=\operatorname{diag}(xx^T)_i^i=\operatorname{Trace}(xx^T),$$because $\operatorname{diag}(xx^T)_i^j=x_ix^j$.