# Why $x^TAx=\text{Tr}(AX)$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming, relaxations

In many optimization resources, when we reformulate an LP to an SDP, we sometimes use the fact that
\begin{equation*}
x^{T}Ax = Tr(AX),
\end{equation*}
where $X=xx^T$ is a number. But when I tried to derive the equation, I can't get the desired result. Namely,
\begin{equation*}
x^{T}Ax = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,j}x_ix_j,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
Tr(AX) = (a_{1,1}+...+a_{n,n})(x_1^2+...+x_n^2).
\end{equation*}
The two polynomials are clearly different: simply, $a_{1,1}x_2^2$ is a term in the second polynomial but not in the first one. Please point out where I missed, thanks!

Comment: $X=xx^T$ is not a number, $x^Tx$ is a number. $X$ is an $n\times n$-matrix.

Comment: @Levent is right (with [one subtlety](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899919)).

Comment: @everyone, thanks for pointing out my (rather silly) confusion!

Answer (score 4):

You've confused $xx^T$ with $x^Tx$, or else you've assumed $x$ is a row vector instead of a column vector. Either way, $A$ is being multiplied with a square matrix of the same shape. So the proof is $x_iA_{ij}x_j=A_{ij}x_jx_i=A_{ij}X_{ji}$.

Answer (score 3):

The two parts are that a one by one matrix is its own trace, so that $x^T Ax= \operatorname{trace} x^TAx .$  Next
$  \operatorname{trace} EF = \operatorname{trace} FE $ when multiplication is defined in both orders. Finally, this does not give arbitrary orders with three terms, just cyclic, so that
$$ \operatorname{trace} EFG = \operatorname{trace} FGE = \operatorname{trace} GEF $$  so that
$$ \operatorname{trace} x^T A x = \operatorname{trace} A x x^T = \operatorname{trace} x x^T A $$